# Why am I getting segmentation fault (core dumped) error in my code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, segmentation-fault, g++

This code is for creating a graph using adjacency-list.
`node` is the structure for horizontal linked list for every element of the vertical linked list,
whereas `graphnode` is the structure for vertical linked list.

The code is compiling properly, but when the first input is given, it shows segmentation fault after it.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node        //struct
{
    struct node *next;
    char value;
};
struct graphnode
{
    struct node *start;
    struct graphnode *down;
    char value;
    int count;
};
graphnode * creategraphnode(char val)
{
    struct graphnode *newnode=new graphnode;
    newnode->start=NULL;
    newnode->down=NULL;
    newnode->value=val;
    newnode->count=0;
    return newnode;
}
node *createnode(char val)
{
    struct node *newnode=new node;
    newnode->next=NULL;
    newnode->value=val;
}
void insertgraphnode(char value,graphnode *graph)
{
    struct graphnode *newnode=creategraphnode(value);
    if(graph==NULL)
    {
        graph=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        graphnode *temp=graph;
        while(temp->down)
            temp=temp->down;
        temp->down=newnode;
    }
}
void insertnode(graphnode *graph)
{
    char val;
    struct node *temp=graph->start;
    cout<<"What is the outdegree of "<<graph->value;
    cin>>graph->count;
    cout<<"\nEnter"<<graph->count<<" nodes separated by space:";
    for(int i=1;i<=graph->count;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        node* newnode=createnode(val);
        temp=newnode;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void display(struct graphnode *graph)
{
    if(graph==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo data to display";
        return;
    }
    struct graphnode *temp=graph;
    while(temp)
    {
        struct node *temp1=temp->start;
        cout<<temp->value<<"=>> ";
        if(temp1==NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            while(temp1)
            {
                cout<<temp1->value<<"-> ";
                temp1=temp1->next;
            }
        }
        cout<<"/\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct graphnode *graph=NULL;
    int totalnodes;
    char val;
    cout<<"\nHow many nodes does the graph contain? : ";
    cin>>totalnodes;
    cout<<"\nEnter "<<totalnodes<<" space separated nodes : ";
    for(int i=1;i<=totalnodes;i++)
    {
        cin>>val;
        insertgraphnode(val,graph);
    }
    struct graphnode *temp=graph;
    while(temp->down)
    {
        insertnode(temp);
        temp=temp->down;
    }
    display(graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a plugin that automatically creates question on SO when a program crushes?

Comment: `struct node *temp=graph->start;` is a problem when the first node is inserted. At that time, `graph` is `NULL`.

Comment: I will not call the function insertnode() unless i have used the function insertgraphnode() before it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, your code has at least three problems.

1) your `createnode()` don't return the created node; add `return newnode;`

2) your `insertgraphnode()` don't change the second parameter in the calling function; so, when you call it in `main()`

insertgraphnode(val,graph);

`graph` is `NULL`; inside `insertgraphnode()` you change the value but outside the function `graph` remain `NULL`; ever. This cause the segmentation fault.

You can solve this changing `insertgraphnode()` so the second parameter is a pointer-to-pointer and passing `&graph`.

Another solution is modify `insertgraphnode()` to return the `graph` value

```
graphnode *  insertgraphnode(char value,graphnode *graph)
{
    struct graphnode *newnode=creategraphnode(value);
    if(graph==NULL)
    {
        graph=newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        graphnode *temp=graph;
        while(temp->down)
            temp=temp->down;
        temp->down=newnode;
    }
    return graph;
}
```

and calling it in this way

```
graph = insertgraphnode(val,graph);
```

3) the `while` in `display()` goes in loop because you don't change the value of `temp`